# UITableView Population Slowness

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to make an app with a calendar being displayed and as soon as a day on the calendar (each day is a UIView with a tap gesture) is tapped, all calendar appointments for that day should be displayed in a UITableView.  I've got this working, but there's a big lag between when the tap occurs and when the data is actually populated into the UITableView.  Here's my code:

```
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

//Access Granted to Calendar by user
[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

// Create the start date components
NSDateFormatter *startFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[startFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"];

NSString *monthNumberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", month];

NSString *startDateString = [[[[[monthNumberString stringByAppendingString:@"/"] stringByAppendingString:dLabel.text] stringByAppendingString:@"/"] stringByAppendingString:yearString] stringByAppendingString:@" 12:01 am"];

NSDate *start = [startFormatter dateFromString:startDateString];

NSLog(@"Start Date: %@", startDateString);

// Create the end date components
NSDateFormatter *endFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[endFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"];

NSString *endDateString = [[[[[monthNumberString stringByAppendingString:@"/"] stringByAppendingString:dLabel.text] stringByAppendingString:@"/"] stringByAppendingString:yearString] stringByAppendingString:@" 11:59 pm"];

NSDate *end = [endFormatter dateFromString:endDateString];
NSLog(@"End Date: %@", endDateString);

// Create the predicate from the event store's instance method
NSPredicate *predicate = [store predicateForEventsWithStartDate:start
                                                            endDate:end
                                                          calendars:nil];


// Fetch all events that match the predicate
events = [store eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];

//Sort the array
events = [events sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compareStartDateWithEvent:)];

int eventCount = [events count];

NSLog(@"%i", eventCount);

for (int i=0; i<eventCount; i++) {
    EKEvent *theEvent = [events objectAtIndex:i];    
    NSLog (@"Element %i = %@", i, theEvent.title);
}

UITableView *dayTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(360, 0, 300, 550)
                                                                 style:UITableViewStylePlain];
dayTableView.backgroundColor = lightBlueColor;
dayTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
dayTableView.delegate = self;
dayTableView.dataSource = self;

[super addSubview:dayTableView];

}];
```

UITableview Delegate Functions:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog (@"I made a section!");
    return 1;    //count of section


}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSLog (@"I made %i rows!", [events count]);
    return [events count];
}



-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *c = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"mycell"];

    EKEvent *theEvent = [events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    c.textLabel.text = theEvent.title;

    NSLog (@"Cell %i = %@", indexPath.row, theEvent.title);



    //c.textLabel.text = @"Calendar Event Goes Here";
    c.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

     //NSLog (@"I made a cell!");

    return c;    


}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{




    return 35;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do some profiling to find out what is taking the time.

Comment: How many events are fetched?

Comment: The slowness is the UITableview.  The events array is populated and printed (via NSLog) really quickly.  Then, theres a long pause before the tableview is displayed or even any of the tableview delegate functions called.  There are on an average of like 3-5 events for each day, not a lot.

Comment: Can you do the setup of the tableview before the block and then just do the `[dayTableView reloadData];` within it?

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys.  Otto, I tried setting up the tableview before the block and then called the reloadData function within, but still nothing.  Everything in the block is being executed quickly, it seems to be doing something after that, that's delaying the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.  When I try to trace the code, I get directed to _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions, which looks like assembly code.  Never seem that before.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  The problem is here:
 [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

the way that the event store is accessed is different on iOS6 and iOS5.  Here's a link that shows the correct way of doing it:

http://fostah.com/ios/2012/09/28/ios6-event-edit.html

Answer (score 0):

Without profiling it is difficult to say what the bottleneck of your code is. However, based on *previous experience* I would say that it is the lines that looks like

```
NSString *startDateString = [[[[[monthNumberString stringByAppendingString:@"/"] stringByAppendingString:dLabel.text] stringByAppendingString:@"/"] stringByAppendingString:yearString] stringByAppendingString:@" 12:01 am"];
```

At least if it is called +20000x (or something) a second. First of all it would be more convienient to write this as

```
NSString *startDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@ 12:01 am", monthNumberString, dLabel.text, yearString];
```

But I fear this would not speed up your program much. I would recommend going back to plain C code and use e.g. `sprintf` instead. You can look up the syntax of it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) as well as some examples of use.